# Phoenix -> csv -> invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I need to upload a CSV dump file to the Phoenix database

Files that did not contain any special characters were loaded without problems

```
./psql.py -t TTT localhost /home/isaev/output.csv -d';'
```

But as soon as I tried to load the same file in which the data fields were met with quotes, I get an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$1.getNextRecord(CSVParser.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$1.hasNext(CSVParser.java:407)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.UpsertExecutor.execute(UpsertExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.CSVCommonsLoader.upsert(CSVCommonsLoader.java:217)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.CSVCommonsLoader.upsert(CSVCommonsLoader.java:182)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixRuntime.main(PhoenixRuntime.java:308)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
    at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.parseEncapsulatedToken(Lexer.java:275)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:450)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$1.getNextRecord(CSVParser.java:395)
    ... 5 more
```

For example on the first line (line 1) I have this entry

5863355029;007320071; ZAO "With a smile for life";True;

---

**I found the solution myself:
 -q'\' 
Can someone come in handy**

Comment: I think you need to specify the delimiter like this - `-d'\;'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your problem using quotes 2 times:

```
5863355029;007320071; ZAO ""With a smile for life"";True;
```

Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes. If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields.

Check this link if you are interested in why: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/delimited_text_mlcp/